# Paypal button images will not stay within <div> in IE with position:fixed

Tags: html, css-position

I have a page using the jQuery Isotope plugin and 2 paypal buttons within each  element of the isotope.  Basically the buttons are positioned fixed within each div, which works in Chrome, but in explorer, and sometimes firefox, they just show up as gigantic buttons at the bottom of the page as if they are not within a div element. Can anybody tell why this would be happening?It may be easier to just go look at the page, www.arcwebsitedesign.com/pumpkins/index.html and the source code, but some of the relevant code is below:

```
<div class="element large symbol pop   " data-symbol="Ca" data-category="pop">                  <!--  1D Logo  -->
  <p class="number" style="z-index:100;">1D</p>
  <img src="http://www.pumpkinpatternstencils.com/uploads/4/8/0/6/4806688/5703606.png?175" width="100%">

   <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="YB75GE8U5G5W2">
    <input type="image" src="img/buy-now-btn1.png" border="0" name="submit" target="0"  style="position:fixed;bottom:17px;left:10px;width:43%;" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
    </form>

    <form target="paypal" action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="XEACZYFQHJGX4">
    <input type="image" src="img/add-cart-btn2.png" border="0" name="submit" target="0"  style="position:fixed;bottom:17px;left:125px;width:43%;" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
  </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed positioning doesn't take into account other elements. Perhaps you meant to use `absolute`.

In any case, inline CSS is ugly. It'd be easier for all of us if you pulled it out of your elements and at least used a `style` tag.

Comment: Yeah, I have a potentially bad habit of doing much of my CSS tweaking inline and then cleaning it up once I get it right.  Actually, the absolute thing was not quite working for me either, but getting rid of the position tag completely and just using bottom:XX;  and left:XX;  fixed it and it works on IE, Chrome, Firefox and Android now.  Thanks for your help!

Comment: That's understandable, but it might still be easier to put your CSS in a style tag near where you're working so you don't have to convert syntax later. Please add your answer below or delete the question.